# How to setStyleSheet to QStandardItem

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a simple `QComboBox`. But instead of using a "traditional" `.addItem('myItemName')` method it creates `QStandardItem` first and then adds it via `QComboBox`'s `.model().appendRow()`. Since now I can access each QStandardItem individually I wonder if there is a way to assign CSS to each of them (to each QStandardItem) individually. The goal is to customize each item displayed in ComboBox pulldown menu. So far I am only able to assign a single CSS style to entire ComboBox globally.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Combo(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Combo, self).__init__()        
        for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
            item=QtGui.QStandardItem(each) 
            self.model().appendRow(item)

tree=Combo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this class has no `setStyleSheet` method, but you can use `setBackground`, `setForeground` and `setTextAlignment` methods. With QBrush you be able to customize elements. Of course it isn't so powerful as styleSheets but better than nothing.

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstandarditem.html

Comment: `.setBackground()` and `.setForeground()` seems to get overwritten if CSS stylesheet is applied to a widget. Or the final result is difficult to predict.